# How to change TimePicker in NativeScript Angular to show the time in 24-hour format?

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

In NativeScript , there is the TimePicker, which one shows a time, but in 12-hour format but i want to set the time in 24 hour format. I cannot see any useful method. Please help

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/time-picker search for 24-h

Comment: but when i use this error show i.e. cannot find name java

Comment: export function onPickerLoaded(args) {
  const timePicker: TimePicker = <TimePicker> args.object;

  if (isAndroid) {
      timePicker.android.setIs24HourView(java.lang.Boolean.TRUE);
      timePicker.hour = 23;
      timePicker.minute = 59;
  }

Comment: I don't understand the error, did you try it like this: `timePicker.android.setIs24HourView(java.lang.Boolean.TRUE);` than you should exchange the java.lang.Boolean.TRUE for "true".

Comment: export class TimesComponent implements OnInit {
  onPickerLoaded(args) {
    const timePicker: TimePicker = <TimePicker> args.object;
  
    
        timePicker.android.setIs24HourView(java.lang.Boolean.TRUE);
        
        timePicker.hour = 23;
        timePicker.minute = 59;
    }
i use this codeand error is cannot find name java

Comment: @sunny It's better if you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: playground sample is here https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=cQmXjf

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have used the starter code from [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/time-picker#time-format) in your playground demo. You just need to do one slight change there.

Replace `java.lang.Boolean.TRUE;` with `true`

The above code is using a native way to check the boolean in. But having a raw boolean is not gonna produce any issues.

Here's the complete snippet -

```
const timePicker = args.object;

if (isAndroid) {
    timePicker.android.setIs24HourView(true);
    timePicker.hour = 23;
    timePicker.minute = 59;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Playground sample has a TypeScript error

> home/home.component.ts (16, 44): Cannot find name 'java'.

All you had to do was to declare the java variable at top of your file, like

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { TimePicker } from "tns-core-modules/ui/time-picker";

declare var java;
```

Alternatively you may install [tns-platform-declarations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-platform-declarations) as a dev dependency in your local project and create `reference.d.ts` as described in the ReadMe file, if you prefer IntelliSense support for native apis.